# Memory allocation of 3-d arrays for reading pixel data of images using libjpeg

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, user-defined-functions

I am trying to copy the pixel data of an image to a matrix using libjpeg. Something is going wrong with the pointers. Please help.

The problem in brief: I pass an `int ***p` pointer to a function which reads pixel data. Within the function, I am able to access the elements `p[i][j][k]` and perform operations on them but when I try to do the same in `main` the program crashes. 
The main function is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<jpeglib.h>
#include"functions.h"

void main(void)
{
    char * file="a.jpg";
    int ***p;                 // to store the pixel values
    int s[2]={0,0};           // to store the dimensions of the image
    read_JPEG_file(file,p,s); // Function that reads the image
    printf("%d",p[0][0][0]);  // This makes the program crash
}
```

The file functions.h reads:

```
int read_JPEG_file(char * file, int ***p, int **s)
{
    int i,j;
    //-----------------libjpeg procedure which I got from the documentation------------
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    cinfo.err=jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

    FILE * infile;      /* source file */
    JSAMPARRAY buffer;      /* Output row buffer */
    int row_stride;
    if ((infile = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
    jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
    row_stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;
    buffer=(*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, row_stride, 1);
    s[0]=cinfo.output_height;
    s[1]=cinfo.output_width;
    p=(int ***)malloc(s[0]*sizeof(int **));
    for (i=0;i<s[0];i++)
    {
        p[i]=(int **)malloc(s[1]*sizeof(int *));
        for (j=0;j<s[1];j++)
        {
            p[i][j]=(int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        }
}

while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) 
    {
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
        for ( i=0; i<cinfo.output_width; i++)
        {
             p[cinfo.output_scanline-1][i][0]=(int)buffer[0][0+3*i];
             p[cinfo.output_scanline-1][i][1]=(int)buffer[0][1+3*i];
             p[cinfo.output_scanline-1][i][2]=(int)buffer[0][2+3*i];
         }
    }

printf("%d",p[0][0][0]); // This works just fine
return 0;
}
```

I know that something is wrong with the memory allocation but I don't know what. I tried another test program and successfully allocated a memory block 500X500X500 integers long, and it was working-it was outputting random integers without crashing- so lack of memory is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your int ***p isn't malloc.
When you send him to read_JPEG_file a second variable int ***p was created.
This second variable was destruct at the end of read_JPEG_file. So you can use p 
in read_JPEG_file but that's all.
There is three way to solve it.
The first and I think the easier to understand is to return p.

```
 int ***read_JPEG_file(char * file, int ***p, int **s) {
     ...
     return p; 
 }

 int main() {
    ...
    p = read_JPEG_file(file, p, s);
 }
```

(It became unnecessary to send p)

The second way is to malloc p in the main and then to send him.
It seems a bit hard to do in your case.

The third is to send the address of p in the main. You will have a (int * * * *p).
You have to take care when you use it.
You can do something like that :

```
 int read_JPEG_file(char * file, int ****p, int **s)
 {
     ...
     *p=(int ***)malloc(s[0]*sizeof(int **));
 }
```

Now you have to use *p instead of p.
*p mean the value that contain the pointer p. p is an int * * * * so his value is the int * * *.

```
 int main()
 {
     ...
     read_JPEG_file(file, &p, s);
 }
```